# Mayavi2 standalone script with command line arguments

Tags: python, enthought, mayavi

I am trying to parse command line argument to a MayaVi2 standalone script. However, the `mayavi2.standalone()` function eats command line arguments before me. For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys, argparse
from mayavi.scripts import mayavi2
from mayavi import mlab

@mayavi2.standalone
def view():
    mayavi.new_scene()
    mlab.test_plot3d()


def parseCmdLineArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple plotting using MayaVi2')
    parser.add_argument('--scale', dest='scale', action='store',help='Sets the axis scaling')
    parser.set_defaults(scale=1.0)
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args=parseCmdLineArgs()
    print "Scale=%g" % args.scale
    view()
```

If call this script `plot.py` and run it as

```
$ plot.py -h
```

I get the `mayavi2.standalone()` help message and not the one for my own parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code of the `mayavi2` module at [GitHub](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/blob/master/mayavi/scripts/mayavi2.py), it is observed that it has code in the global name space. Some of the code will execute command line parsing. Since Python code is run from top to down, the problem can be solved by a reordering of the code:

```
import sys, argparse

def parseCmdLineArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple plotting using MayaVi2')
    parser.add_argument('--scale', dest='scale', action='store',help='Sets the axis scaling')
    parser.set_defaults(scale=1.0)
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args=parseCmdLineArgs()

from mayavi.scripts import mayavi2
from mayavi import mlab

@mayavi2.standalone
def view():
    mayavi.new_scene()
    mlab.test_plot3d()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Scale=%g" % args.scale
    view()
```